# Adobe Reader 11.0.9 crashes when using "tools" or "form and Sign"

Tags: pdf, crash, adobe-reader

I recently updated my company's Adobe reader to 11.0.9 via GPO. I followed instructions here: http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/37467-how-to-create-a-slipstreamed-adobe-acrobat-reader-msi-for-gpo-deployment

I downloaded the MSP for the 11.0.9 MUI.  I patched it over a copy of my 11.0.7 MUI.MSI installation file. Then I released it through GPO.
Now when any of my users open a PDF with the "tools" or "Form and Sign" right-side-bar open, Reader crashes.  it goes to "not responding", then a popup for "check for solutions" or "close program".  I instructed my users to open Reader (without a file) and close the Right-side-bar (by clicking "tools" or "form and sign").  Then files open properly.
However a user needs the "form and sign" feature so when she clicks that, Reader crashes.

I have tried to uninstall Reader 11.0.9, then allow GPO to install it.  but it still crashes.
I have uninstalled 11.0.9, and installed 11.0.7 and 11.0.7 works properly.  So I believe it is with 11.0.9.

Is there anyone having the same problem?  Or does anyone have a solution? Or do you think I should retracting the update therefore everyone is back at 11.0.7?

PS the problems are appearing on Windows 7 Computers; I have not check Win XP computers.

Comment: Why did you skip the .8 release?

Comment: I skipped 11.0.8 because I wasn't able to create it correctly.  It has something to do with it being a "SEC" release. I forgot where, but it said that 11.0.9 was a quarterly release.  11.0.8 was classified as something else.  But do you think I should install 11.0.8 then 11.0.9?

Comment: I would at least try it.  Outside of that I would go back to 11.0.7 after reporting the problem to Adobe

Comment: so on one of the computers having hte problem, I uninstalled 11.0.9.  I installed 11.0.0, then update to 11.0.7, then 11.0.8, then 11.0.9.  It now works properly.  It just sucks now because I have to figure out how to do this on the remaining 50+ computers.

Comment: Can't you just push 11.0.8 once week then push 11.0.9 another week?  You can also contact Adobe for support because I suspect you found some sort of bug.

Comment: Everyone has been updated to 11.0.9.  Are you saying to retract 11.0.9, then push 11.0.8, then push 11.0.9?

Comment: Yes; you more or less confirmed if you go from .7 to .8 then to .9 the problem does not surface

Comment: It seems many people are [having this problem with .9](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1583462).  Did you ever find a definite solution?

Comment: Sorry I have not resolved this issue.  I have tried to patch the 11.0.0 with .7, and .7->.8->.9 and it has not worked.  I might be required to install .9 manually on the users that need it.

Comment: Since 11.0.10 just came out, I used it to patch 11.0.0.  I used Group Policy to uninstall 11.0.7 (rather than install on top of).  then installed 11.0.10.  I have tried on a few machines and it is working correctly.